# Unknown error, the response body from fetch is undefined

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to register user on Cognito userpool with cognito.signup. The method works. I get the SMS with temporary password and the user is registered. The problem is that i get an error:

> Unknown error, the response body from fetch is undefined

I already have node-fetch on the project and is set with :

```
global.fetch = require("node-fetch");
```

This is my register service:

```
const AmazonCognitoIdentity = require('amazon-cognito-identity-js');
global.fetch = require("node-fetch");

    module.exports.post = async (username,name,email,phoneNumber) => {
        const environment = {
            UserPoolId: 'xxxxxx',
            ClientId: 'xxxxxxx',
        }
        return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
            const userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(environment);
            const emailData = {
                Name: 'email',
                Value: email
            };
            const phoneData = {
                Name: 'phone_number',
                Value: phoneNumber
            };
            const userData = {
                Name: 'name',
                Value: name
            };
            const emailAttribute = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserAttribute(emailData);
            const userAttribute = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserAttribute(userData);
            const phoneAttribute = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserAttribute(phoneData);

            userPool.signUp(username,'ASDas2aSA@',[emailAttribute,,phoneAttribute,userAttribute], null, (err,data) => {
            if(err){
                reject(new Error(JSON.parse(err)));
            }
            resolve(JSON.parse(data));
            });
        });
    }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So far the current *"fix"* is to make the changes in the **/src/Client.js** file for the `amazon-cognito-identity-js` module so you can see an actual callback. There is an open pull request for the requested changes [here](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/pull/2181/files).